# Pandas: extract and select data from columns using a pattern

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

My data contains a structure similar to this (reduced to 2 elements, but there are tens):

```
Variable        elem_1_pre    elem_1_post   elem_2_pre    elem_2_post
Observation1    present       absent        absent        present
Observation2    absent        present       present       absent
```

The ultimate objective is to select observations (and possibly the associated column names) that are present in `pre` but absent in `post` and vice versa.

In other words, an operation like (pseudocode)

```
("present" in *_pre and "absent" in *_post) or
("present" in *_post and "absent" in *_pre)
```

I'm thinking `groupby` could be used for this. Is such a thing possible with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in your DataFrame are exactly the strings `'present'` and `'absent'`, then you could convert the string values to boolean values with

```
In [17]: df.values == 'present'
Out[17]: 
array([[ True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Once you have boolean values, you can use the NumPy XOR logical operator, `^`, to combine two columns into the desired value:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['present absent absent present'.split(),
                   'absent present present absent'.split()],
                  columns='elem_1_pre elem_1_post elem_2_pre elem_2_post'.split(),
                  index='Observation1 Observation2'.split(),)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values == 'present',
                  columns=df.columns,
                  index=df.index)
print(df)
#              elem_1_pre elem_1_post elem_2_pre elem_2_post
# Observation1       True       False      False        True
# Observation2      False        True       True       False

for i in range(1,3):
    elem = ['elem_{i}_{s}'.format(i=i, s=suf) for suf in ('pre', 'post')]
    change = 'elem_{i}_change'.format(i=i)
    df[change] = df[elem[0]] ^ df[elem[1]]
print(df.ix[:, 'elem_1_change elem_2_change'.split()])
```

yields

```
             elem_1_change elem_2_change
Observation1          True          True
Observation2          True          True
```

Comment: They are exactly those because I build the source DataaFrame, so I'll give this a go. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You wondered if `groupby` could be used here, so I'll mention how it can be.  Short version, although I'd probably write this in two lines for clarity:

```
(df == 'present').groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit("_", 1)[0], axis=1).sum() == 1
```

---

First, we can start from an example dataframe, compliments of @unutbu (NOTE: this is different from yours, so that the output isn't all True):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['present absent absent absent'.split(),
                   'present present present absent'.split()],
                  columns='elem_1_pre elem_1_post elem_2_pre elem_2_post'.split(),
                  index='Observation1 Observation2'.split(),)
>>> df
             elem_1_pre elem_1_post elem_2_pre elem_2_post
Observation1    present      absent     absent      absent
Observation2    present     present    present      absent
```

We can determine which of these are `present`:

```
>>> p = df == "present"
>>> p
             elem_1_pre elem_1_post elem_2_pre elem_2_post
Observation1       True       False      False       False
Observation2       True        True       True       False
```

Then, what we really want to do is group the columns into the "elem_1" bits.  You can use string methods or regular expressions or even the indexes if they're ordered.  I like using string methods, so we'll split the column name by the first `_` on the right.  To group over the columns, we use `axis=1`:

```
>>> for k, g in p.groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit("_", 1)[0], axis=1):
    print 'group key:', k
    print g
...     
group key: elem_1
             elem_1_pre elem_1_post
Observation1       True       False
Observation2       True        True
group key: elem_2
             elem_2_pre elem_2_post
Observation1      False       False
Observation2       True       False
```

We want to count the True values in a row and see if there's only one.  True ~ 1 and False ~ 0, so we can use `sum`:

```
>>> p.groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit("_", 1)[0], axis=1).sum()
              elem_1  elem_2
Observation1       1       0
Observation2       2       1
```

and then

```
>>> p.groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit("_", 1)[0], axis=1).sum() == 1
             elem_1 elem_2
Observation1   True  False
Observation2  False   True
```

Or, putting it all together:

```
>>> grouped = (df == "present").groupby(lambda x: x.rsplit("_", 1)[0], axis=1)
>>> answer = grouped.sum() == 1
>>> answer
             elem_1 elem_2
Observation1   True  False
Observation2  False   True
```